# Stern-Gerlach-Experiment with j=1 atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Suppose you do a Stern-Gerlach experiment with atoms in a $j=1$ state. There would be three separate beams ($m_j = -1, 0, 1$) coming out of the apperatus. But what would be the relative distribution of atoms in these beams?

On first thought I would say that the distribution should be $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{3}$. But considering the "classical" distribution of the projections of the angular momentum onto one axis I could imagine that there could be more atoms in the $m_j = 0$ state. This would still be compatible with symmetry considerations.

To state the question differently: how does the density matrix of an unpolarized beam of $j=1$ atoms look like?

Comment: Typo(?) in the question (v1): $j=0$ should be $j=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The z-projection of the angular momentum of a completely unpolarized system is distributed uniformly both classically and quantum mechanically.

In quantum mechanics, the density matrix of a three state system
is given by:
$\rho = \frac{1}{3}(I_3+\overrightarrow{n}.\overrightarrow{\lambda})$, where $I_3$ is the three dimensional unit matrix.
$\overrightarrow{n}$ is the polarization vector and $\overrightarrow{\lambda}$ is a vector of Gell-mann matrices.

In a fully polarized system $\overrightarrow{n}.\overrightarrow{n}= 1$, while in the case of a completely unpolarized system:
$\overrightarrow{n} = 0$. In this case:

$\rho = \frac{1}{3}(I_3)$. Therefore, the three states are equally distributed.

In classical mechanics, the phase space of a spin system is the unit sphere. The z-component of a unit angular momentum system is given by:

$ J_z = cos(\theta)$.

Where $\theta$ is the inclination angle. A completely unpolarized classical angular momentum should be distributed uniformly with respect to the surface area of the sphere which is the classical phase space.
The area of a spherical zone of thickness $h$ is $S = 2 \pi R h$, where $R=1$ is the sphere radius (This result was already known to [Archimedes](http://descartes.cnice.mec.es/descartes2/previas_web/materiales_didacticos/ing_redondos/arquime1.htm)). Therefore the z-coordinate is uniformly distributed on the sphere and the z-component of the angular momentum expressed as:

$ J_z = \frac{z}{R}$

is linear in $z$, therefore also uniformly distributed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I fully agree on the quantum mechanical part. But I don't understand the reasoning for the classical counterpart: shouldn't the R in the formular for S be the "in-plane" radius (distance from the z-axis, not from the origin)? $S = 2\pi \times \sin(\theta) h$?

Comment: Please see the derivation in: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zone.html

Comment: Okay, this came really surprising for me. I didn't expect this. Thanks for the hint and the URL. I would upvote you're answer, if I were allowed to ;-)

Comment: Trying to compute this on my own, I found a much simpler derivation for this surface: With $z = R \cos(\theta)$ one can do the integration in spherical coordinates:
$A = R \int_0^{2\pi} \text{d} \phi \int_{\arccos(a/R)}^{\arccos(b/R)} \text{d} \theta \sin(\theta)$ $=$ $2 \pi R \int_a^b \text{d} \left(\cos(\theta)\right) = 2 \pi R (b-a)$. Thanks again!

Comment: One more remark: it is interesting to see that Otto Stern probably did exactly the same mistake as me: See http://www.springerlink.com/content/wm65pq5t22706x62/fulltext.pdf, page 252. He writes: "Nun ist die Anzahl der Atome, für die $\theta$ einen bestimmten Wert hat, proportional $\sin(\theta)$". Translated: "The number of atoms for which $\theta$ has a certain value is proportional to $\sin(\theta)$".

Comment: No, he is correct. $\theta$ isn't uniformly distributed with respect to the surface elements of the sphere, but $J_z$ which is proportional to $cos(\theta)$ is uniformly distributed. You can verify that according to the random variable distribution transformation law: $p_{J_z}= \frac{p_{\theta}}{|\frac{d(J_z)}{d\theta}|}$, where $p$ denotes the distribution density

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks for pointing out the difference. But for the "classical" outcome of the experiment, it would mean that the atoms where uniformly distributed on the screen, because the deflection is proportional to $J_z$.